# Multithreading Python Code For Excel Sheets

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

So I've watched a couple of tutorials and I believe I've implemented the threading module correctly into my code. It seems to be working but I'm not sure if the time it takes to execute has decreased. I've placed my code below for critique. The code should update the two excel sheets simultaneously, instead of consecutively.  Let me know what you guys think.

```
import win32com.client  
import time
from threading import Thread


xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application") #opens excel


class thr1(Thread):
    def run(self):
        wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Testing\example.xlsx")
        xl.Visible = False
        time.sleep(15)
        wb.Refreshall()
        wb.Save()
        wb.Close()
        print('completed.')


class thr2(Thread):
    def run(self):
        wb2 = xl.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Testing\example2.xlsx")
        xl.Visible = False
        time.sleep(15)
        wb2.Refreshall()
        wb2.Save()
        wb2.Close()
        print('completed.')

t1 = thr1()
t2 = thr2()

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Comment: You should not call `.run()` directly. What you ought to do, is to call `.start()` and then let the `Thread`s do their magic. As written, it executes sequentially and in the main thread.

Comment: @JohanL So "def(start)" instead of def(run) should decrease runtime?

Comment: No, `t1.start()` and `t2.start()` at the end, should allow the threads to run in parallel. You should still define the `def run(self):` methods as they are called from `.start()` (after the new thread is created).

Comment: So I edited my code & now I'm getting an error message....... Exception in thread Thread-##:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()

Comment: Your `Thread`classes are named `thr1` and `thr2`but you try to instantiate them as `xl1` and `xl2`. Is this just a typo when writing the question, otherwise this will give _some_ kind of error.

Comment: @JohanL yeah that was typo, I edited